# RPi 3 B - On-Board wifi not present

Tags: wifi, hardware, driver

I have this Raspberry Pi 3 B, and it seems that the on-board wi-fi is not showing at all.

I have downloaded and flashed a fresh image of raspbian, but that did not help. If I use an external USB wifi module, that works.

If I issue ifconfig there is no wifi adapter listed (unless I use the external one that I mentioned earlier.

I have also tried sudo apt-get...
... update
...upgrade
...dist-upgrade

I did not do anything configuration to use enable the wifi. I am not aware if there is anything such.
I played around with wpa_supplicant, and added my network there like:

```
network={
ssid="mynetwork"
psk="***"
}
```

Any ideas?

Have a great day!

UPDATE:
Here is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: All I can suggest is 1 - defective pi, or 2 - it's NOT a pi 3

Comment: Do you tried `rpi-update`?

Comment: Can you post the result of a cat /etc/network/interfaces command? It should contain (among other things) something like: allow-hotplug wlan0 iface wlan0 inet manual wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf (Ooooh, I've just realise mine has two. I must post a question as to why!)

Comment: Yes I did try rpi-update

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I downloaded RASPBIAN JESSIE May 2016 version, then it start working.